# Disable web authentification in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config

I use ASP .Net 4 and I have a project using the form web authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/" timeout="7200" />
</authentication>
```

I have a web service in the same project and I want to disable this web authentication for one page (a web service)

I tryed that code :

```
<location path="WSBaseCentrale.asmx" allowOverride="false">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

But I've a 302 redirection to the form logon.
Is it possible to disable it ?

**Edit**

I tryied that and it doesn't work better.
When I access to the page (http://localhost/App/WSBaseCentrale.asmx) I am always redirected to the form page (http://localhost/App/) with an HTTP 302 redirection.

```
<location path="WSBaseCentrale.asmx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

**Edit 2**

Some others facts :

- the anonymous user in iis is activated.
- When I use firebug (I desactive the cache and I remove the cookie), I can reproduce the problem every time. Moreover, I can see in the response header that the server send a Location directive to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `allowOverride="false"`

Also remove `<allow users="?"/>` and add it in place of `<allow users="*"/>`

Finally, make sure your `webservice` is in the root Directory, otherwise you have to specify the path accordingly.

Comment: I finally create another project. Your answer gave more elements although I didn't manage to my needs. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2):

This works on my web site

```
<location path="Services">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<location path="WSBaseCentrale.asmx">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Did you try this?

---

Also you should check the anonymous authentication settings for your IIS, may be you just can't view your site anonymously.

Comment: yes I tryied this. But same result when I access to the page, I'm redirected to the form page (by a 302 redirection)

Comment: WHere is WSBaseCentrale.asmx placed? In the root directory?

Comment: @Philippe Sohm, try to remove the allowOverride="false", as @Muhammad Akhtar have advised. At the other side, 302 redirect can cache itself, if you are checking not locally.

Comment: the anonymous user in iis is activated. When I use firebug, if I desactive the cache, and if I remove the cookie, I can reproduce the problem every time. Moreover, I can see in the response header that the server send a Location directive to the browser